# Ksql - streams from topics with different partition numbers

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to join messages from 2 different kafka topics which have different partition numbers with ksqlDB.
When i create streams from each topics and trying to join them, ksqlDB does not allow bec. of different partition numbers in base topics.

When i do the below steps for each topic:
->create stream from root topic,
->create another stream from first stream with new topic with 1 partition (reduce 4 to 1)
i cant' t see any data at the final stream which has 1 partition.

Is there any solution to join 2 topics with different partition numbers in ksqlDB?

Comment: _cant' t see any data at the final stream which has 1 partition_ - Then the join isn't the problem. Please show a [mcve] of your data and queries

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Problem wasn't the number of partitions.
Problem was that the join was on fields with different data type ( bigint and double ).

Answer (score 0):

[https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/partition-data/#:~:text=The%20input%20records%20for%20joins,where%20the%20partition%20counts%20differ](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/partition-data/#:%7E:text=The%20input%20records%20for%20joins,where%20the%20partition%20counts%20differ).

> If the sides of the join have different partition counts, you may want to change the partition counts of the source topics, or repartition one side to match the partition count of the other.
> The following example creates a repartitioned stream, maintaining the existing key, with the specified number of partitions.

```
CREATE STREAM products_rekeyed 
  WITH (PARTITIONS=6) AS 
  SELECT * FROM products;
```